# Raspberry Pi model b+ has stopped working

Tags: pi-2, power-supply, boot-issues

I am using a Raspberry Pi model b+ to drive a wheelchair. I am running the motors through relay modules. The signal to the relay module is given from  the Pi.

Also a GSM module and voice recognition module is connected to the Pi. As well as a heartbeat sensor. Earlier when I had connected jst, the voice module, relays and heartbeat sensor, it was working fine.

As soon as I connected the GSM module, the Pi suddenly stopped working. Can this be due to heating? How can I know if the Pi is salvageable or not? And due to what reasons could it have stopped working?

Comment: Also when I individually connected the modules, it worked when. It was only when all the modules were connected together that the pi stopped working. The relays, GSM module and voice module were given supply from 12v battery and were given a common ground. Is it possible that if I give separate supplies to one or more modules it might not harm the harm?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for a Pi stopping when you add a new peripheral is current overload.  The polyfuse limits the current at about 2 amps.  If you exceed that value the polyfuse will "blow" and the Pi will stop working.

The polyfuse resets after it has cooled down for a few hours.

Have you got a meter to check current consumption?

Comment: Oh ohky.. I don't have a meter for checking the current consumption.. But I can wait it out.. And check again after a few hours.. Thanks a lot for the insight.