# My raspbery Pi 3 B would not boot and when it does it freezes

Tags: pi-3, boot-issues

I use 2 amp , 5 volt power adapter in my raspberry pi 3 2015 model and it does not boot , after leaving it for 2 days if I try then it boots up and then freezes and if i turn off the power it does not boot for about 2 days and the same thing happens .The same power adapter and memory card works fine with raspberry pi 3+ model 2017 and raspberry pi 4.

Comment: *"it does not boot for about 2 days"* -> Although two days might be a bit long this implies the **polyfuse** is in play: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47347/5538 --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse This is only the case if it shuts down after restarting again ("freeze" implies the power stays on normally) and alas, even if it were so this would not mean it is not permanently damaged; most likely the permanent is causing a short which is causing the fuse to blow.

Comment: thanks for providing the answer as stated in  Wikipedia the polyfuse protects device from over current  but i have no peripheral attached to the pi and the power adapter i used is 2 amp 5 volt is there something that is causing this over current in PI?      (yeah 2 days might be long but I kept on trying every hour left for 2 days and pi booted but froze and i again tried for few hours and the kept in my drawer for 2 days then it booted fine for about 20 min and froze again and didn't boot and there is no power going to the USB port)

Comment: If it won't power up for two days at a time, there is clearly something physically damaged.  It could be just a loose connection.  It could be a variety of things, but diagnosing it precisely if you do not have the skills is probably not a worthwhile pursuit, because *fixing* it, even if you know the problem, will almost certainly be impossible. Of course, you would like to know the cause so you can avoid the same problem in the future, but unless you can remember doing something unusual (and it sounds like you cannot), that probably isn't going to happen either.

Comment: So, short story: *It's broken, the end.*  You are of course welcome to leave this question open, someone may have more to add.